# box API 1 token and box AP1 2 tokens

Tags: .net, access-token, box-api

I have a system the currently integrates with box using API 1.0.  My existing user have tokens that were issued by API 1.0 thus these tokens do not expire.  I see that API 1.0 is being deprecated in Dec.  Reviewing API 2.0 access tokens expire in 1 hour.

The question I have is that when I make the switch to API 2.0 will all my existing users have to get new access tokens.  If no, will the API 1.0 generated tokens never expire?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your users will have to re-authenticate through the OAuth 2 flow in order to get OAuth 2 tokens.

When the V1 API is deprecated, all parts of it will cease to function, including any V1 auth tokens.